# Executing bare metal qemu execution with -pflash command

Tags: gcc, arm, qemu

I have a website [Hello world for bare metal ARM using QEMU](http://balau82.wordpress.com/2010/02/28/hello-world-for-bare-metal-arm-using-qemu/) that teaches how to run `qemu` for versatilePB.

The website example uses `-kernel` option to load the binary image into 0x10000; I just assume that the binary is loaded into 0x10000 internally with the `-kernel`.

This is the command `qemu-system-arm -M versatilepb -m 128M  -kernel test.bin -serial stdio`, and the source can be found at - https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/10773282/2014/b1.zip

The ld setup is as follows:

```
ENTRY(_Reset)
SECTIONS
{
 . = 0x10000;
 .startup . : { startup.o(.text) } 
 ...
}
```

Start up assembly is simple as follows:

```
.global _Reset
_Reset:
 LDR sp, =stack_top
 BL c_entry
 B .
```

The main c code (c_entry) is as follows:

```
volatile unsigned int * const UART0DR = (unsigned int *)0x101f1000;

void print_uart0(const char *s) {
 while(*s != '\0') { /* Loop until end of string */
 *UART0DR = (unsigned int)(*s); /* Transmit char */
 s++; /* Next char */
 }
}

void c_entry() {
 print_uart0("Hello world!\n");
}
```

I need to modify the code to boot without `-kernel`, but with `-pflash` to emulate as if the binary is read from the flash drive. This is my approach in trying to make it work:

#### Change the startup assembly and test.ld

I just used the other example from the same author of my example: http://balau82.wordpress.com/2010/02/14/simplest-bare-metal-program-for-arm/
This is the startup code:

```
.section INTERRUPT_VECTOR, "x"
.global _Reset
_Reset:
  B Reset_Handler /* Reset */
  B . /* Undefined */
  B . /* SWI */
  B . /* Prefetch Abort */
  B . /* Data Abort */
  B . /* reserved */
  B . /* IRQ */
  B . /* FIQ */

Reset_Handler:
  LDR sp, =stack_top
  BL c_entry
  B .
```

This is the test.ld

```
ENTRY(_Reset)
SECTIONS
{
 . = 0x0;
 .text : {
 startup.o (INTERRUPT_VECTOR)
 *(.text)
 }
 .data : { *(.data) }
 .bss : { *(.bss COMMON) }
 . = ALIGN(8);
 . = . + 0x1000; /* 4kB of stack memory */
 stack_top = .;
}
```

#### Update the build code

After the build to get the test.bin, I used the `dd` command to create a flash binary.

```
arm-none-eabi-as -mcpu=arm926ej-s -g startup.s -o startup.o
arm-none-eabi-gcc -c -mcpu=arm926ej-s -g test.c -o test.o
arm-none-eabi-ld -T test.ld test.o startup.o -o test.elf
arm-none-eabi-objcopy -O binary test.elf test.bin
dd if=/dev/zero of=flash.bin bs=4096 count=4096
dd if=test.bin of=flash.bin bs=4096 conv=notrunc
```

#### qemu execution

Executed qemu to get this error message.

```
qemu-system-arm -M versatilepb -m 128M  -pflash flash.bin -nographic
>> failed to read the initial flash content
>> Initialization of device cfi.pflash01 failed
```

What might be wrong? I uploaded the examples and sample code.

- not working with -pflash: https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/10773282/2014/b2.zip

Comment: WAY too many external links, this ticket will have no value to SO readers...

Comment: How did you generate flash.bin?

Comment: @hesham_EE: The last two lines of code in "Update the build code" did it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems like that the `-M` option affects the other option. 
I tried with `-M connex` to use gumstix board, and it works fine.

The other thing that I notice was that with `-M versatilepb`, I had to use `-kernel` for loading and running the program.